# Best practices for building a scalable Java EE online shopping application

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, scalability

I would like to know some best practices which can be followed while designing an online shopping application. I am interested to know the following aspects majorly.

1. Scalability - How can I make sure that my design will be capable for meeting the scalability perspectives of an expected growth of users @ 20% every year.
2. Performance bottlenecks.

Please share some thoughts around these two aspects.

Comment: ["*If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.*"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) - I can

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to software design you can start with some layered architecture :

1. DAO Layer
2. Service Layer
3. Controller/UI Layer

By applying these layers you can extend you application in future without any problems.

Example : [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011330/java-ee-best-design-approach-business-logic-layer)

Answer (score 0):

As the member already talked about the 3 tier approach above; I will not dwell into it.
However I think you wanted to find more explanation on the data scalability point of view.

Answer to Question#1:
more and more modern high data intensive applications are leaning towards horizontal data scaling approach. Such as sharding of DB, using BigData or noSQL environments which allow horizontal scalability of data bases.

The 3 tier approach enables such scalability changes to be carried out easily.

Answer to Question#2:
I am not sure if your question elaborates the bottleneck areas correctly. There can be bottlenecks in back end/server side [I am making an assumption that you are talking about a web based application] or front end (browser side). Sorry to say but it's hard to elaborate a broad term like "Performance Bottleneck". More concrete problem statement can be helpful in receiving an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Online shopping application I'd assume to be something like MVC.

1. I won't jump directly on noSQL databases unless your dataset size is more than 10GB or 100GB. Because up to that the RDBMSs scale up really well. So if you think your dataset is going to be above that range, go ahead for noSQL.
2. It's certainly a broad question. Some clues could be: keep a 'profiling' eye on all the backend queries, on all the api calls & all the processes. It can be expanded way further like the db design (normality of your tables), indexes (based on your queries/search/other criteria requirements) need to be well designed/thought of based on your requirements. Other than these it's definitely better to follow coding best practices to make sure your codebase is maintainable for your developers down the line. You could follow something like [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-15-best-practices-for-writing-super-readable-code--net-8118) & there are many resources out there including the ones exclusively for frontend & backend. It all again boils down to what you really want to design/develop.
   Regarding performance, you'll likely also need a distributed caching mechanism like [Cacheonix](https://www.cacheonix.org) or [Apache ignite](https://ignite.apache.org) to ensure cache coherence among your servers.